# deleting second comma in data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Ok so I have a table called PEOPLE that has a name column. In the name column is a name, but its totally a mess. For some reason its not listed such as last, first middle. It's sitting like last,first,middle and last first (and middle if there)  are separated by a comma.. two commas if the person has a middle name.

example:

```
     smith,steve
     smith,steve,j
     smith,ryan,tom
```

I'd like the second comma taken away (for parsing reason ) spaces put after existing first comma so the above would come out looking like:

```
    smith, steve
    smith, steve j
    smith, ryan tom
```

Ultimately I'd like to be able to parse the names into first, middle, and last name fields, but that's for another post :_0. I appreciate any help.

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Drop table T1;
Create table T1(Name varchar(100));
Insert T1 Values
('smith,steve'),
('smith,steve,j'),
('smith,ryan,tom');



UPDATE T1
SET Name=
            CASE CHARINDEX(',',name,    CHARINDEX(',',name)+1) WHEN 
                0 THEN Name
            ELSE
                LEFT(name,CHARINDEX(',',name,   CHARINDEX(',',name)+1)-1)+' ' +
                RIGHT(name,LEN(Name)-CHARINDEX(',',name,    CHARINDEX(',',name)+1)) 
            END
Select * from T1
```

Comment: This mostly worked but needed 


set name = REPLACE(name, ',',', ') 

to add a space after the first comma. But other than that worked great!

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work. Not the most concise but avoids cursors.

```
 DECLARE @people TABLE (name varchar(50)) 
INSERT INTO @people 
SELECT 'smith,steve' 
UNION 
SELECT 'smith,steve,j' 
UNION 
SELECT 'smith,ryan,tom' 
UNION 
SELECT 'commaless'

SELECT name,   
CASE    
WHEN CHARINDEX(',',name) > 0 THEN
        CASE
            WHEN CHARINDEX(',',name,CHARINDEX(',',name) + 1) > 0 THEN 
                    STUFF(STUFF(name, CHARINDEX(',',name,CHARINDEX(',',name) + 1), 1, ' '),CHARINDEX(',',name),1,', ')
            ELSE 
                    STUFF(name,CHARINDEX(',',name),1,', ')
        END
    ELSE name
   END AS name2 
FROM @people
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a table function to split apart the names with a delimiter and for XML Path to stitch them back together, we can get what you're looking for! Hope this helps!

```
Declare @People table(FullName varchar(200))

Insert Into @People Values ('smith,steve')
Insert Into @People Values ('smith,steve,j')
Insert Into @People Values ('smith,ryan,tom')
Insert Into @People Values ('smith,john,joseph Jr')

Select p.*,stuff(fn.FullName,1,2,'') as ModifiedFullName
From @People p
Cross Apply (
    select 
        Case When np.posID<=2 Then ', ' Else ' ' End+np.Val
    From @People n
    Cross Apply Custom.SplitValues(n.FullName,',') np
    Where n.FullName=p.FullName
    For XML Path('')
) fn(FullName)
```

Output:

```
ModifiedFullName
smith, steve
smith, steve j
smith, ryan tom
smith, john joseph Jr
```

SplitValues table function definition:

```
/*
This Function takes a delimited list of values and returns a table containing 
each individual value and its position.
*/

CREATE FUNCTION [Custom].[SplitValues]
(
      @List varchar(max)
    , @Delimiter varchar(1)
)
RETURNS 
@ValuesTable table
(
    posID int
    ,val varchar(1000)
)
AS
BEGIN
    WITH Cte AS 
    ( 
        SELECT CAST('<v>' + REPLACE(@List,  @Delimiter, '</v><v>') + '</v>' AS XML) AS val
    ) 
    INSERT @ValuesTable (posID,val)
    SELECT row_number() over(Order By x) as posID, RTRIM(LTRIM(Split.x.value('.', 'VARCHAR(1000)'))) AS val 
    FROM Cte 
    CROSS APPLY val.nodes('/v') Split(x)
    RETURN
END

GO
```

Answer (score 0):

String manipulation in SQLServer, outside of writing your own User Defined Function, is limited but you can use the PARSENAME function for your purposes here. It takes a string, splits it on the period character, and returns the segment you specify.

Try this:

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(100) = 'smith,ryan,tom'
SELECT REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE(@name), ',', '.'), 1)) + ', ' +
       REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE(@name), ',', '.'), 2)) +
       COALESCE(' ' + REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE(@name), ',', '.'), 3)), '')
```

Result: smith, ryan tom

If you set @name to 'smith,steve' instead, you'll get:

Result: smith, steve

Segment 1 actually gives you the last segment, segment 2 the second to last etc. Hence I've used REVERSE to get the order you want. In the case of 'steve,smith', segment 3 will be null, hence the COALESCE to add an empty string if that is the case. The REPLACE of course changes the commas to periods so that the split will work.

Note that this is a bit of a hack. PARSENAME will not work if there are more than four parts and this will fail if the name happens to contain a period. However if your data conforms to these limitations, hopefully it provides you with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Caveat: it sounds like your data may be inconsistently formatted. In that case, applying any automated treatment to it is going to be risky. However, you could try:

```
UPDATE people SET name = REPLACE(name, ',', ' ') 
UPDATE people SET name = LEFT(name, CHARINDEX(' ', name)-1)+ ', '
                       + RIGHT(name, LEN(name) - CHARINDEX(' ', name)
```

That'll work for the three examples you give. What it will do to the rest of your set is another question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example with CHARINDEX() and SUBSTRING

```
WITH yourTable
AS
(
    SELECT names
    FROM
    (
        VALUES ('smith,steve'),('smith,steve,j'),('smith,ryan,tom')
    ) A(names)
)

SELECT  names AS old,
        CASE
            WHEN comma > 0
                THEN    SUBSTRING(spaced_names,0,comma + 1)             --before the comma
                        + SUBSTRING(spaced_names,comma + 2,1000)    --after the comma
            ELSE spaced_names
        END AS new
FROM yourTable
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CHARINDEX(',',names,CHARINDEX(',',names) + 1),REPLACE(names,',',', ')) AS CA(comma,spaced_names)
```